# TFS 2010 Global Field Editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfs-process-template

Working with TFS 2010 Power Tools, and able to edit template Fields via Process Editor.

However the Fields tab in the editor does not show "all" fields in that Project Collection.

For example if you create a field CompanyName.FooField in Team-Project-A, you will not see it when opening the Process Editor for Team-Project-B within the same collection.

Yet, you are not allowed to create a new field with the same Name or RefName. TFS insists on Name & RefName to be unique in the Project Collection.

You are allowed to create a New field in Team-Project-B using the same Name & RefName for FooField - I'm assuming field is somehow re-used across 2 Team-Projects.

After doing some research, TFS allows for fields to be re-used as long as they are within the same Project Collection (can be in dif. team projects).

Work Item Field Explorer (Tools/ProcessEditor) shows a READ-ONLY view of all fields.

Its obvious that TFS maintains a "Global" Field definition on the Project Collection Level, yet there seem to be additional association with individual Team Project.

It would be extremely helpful if there was a similar way to EDIT all fields at once within a Project Collection as opposed to bouncing between Process Editor windows for each Team Project.

Is there anyway to do that or has anyone faced a similar problem?

Comment: Just to clarify I'm looking a way to view and Edit all custom fields created for all Team Projects, all within 1 Project Collection. Process editor allows you to edit only 1 Team Project at once, and Field Explorer only gives you a read-only view.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible because two collection projects are necessarily created on two different data bases, so the difficulty of achieving what you want, but betweentwo  projects it is possible because they are on the same database instance.

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd236915.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'm only looking for a way to better manage Custom Fields between Team Projects that are within a single Project Collection.

Comment: Happy to help you Alex

Comment: Aghilas, thanks for confirming that but my question was about a Global Editor for all Team Project fields within a Project Collection. TFS Power Tools has Field Explorer that allows you to view all fields, but not edit. I'm looking for a way to edit all fields at once.

Comment: Alex happy to help you, you must develop custommize library for editing